# Export Excel range/sheet to formatted text file

Tags: .net, sql, vba, excel

I have been tasked with creating a reusable process for our Finance Dept to upload our payroll to the State(WI) for reporting. I need to create something that takes a sheet or range in Excel and creates a specifically formatted text file.

***THE FORMAT***

- Column 1 - A Static Number, never changes, position 1-10
- Column 2 - A Dynamic Param filled at runtime for Quarter/Year, position 11-13
- Column 3 - SSN, no hyphens or spaces,
  filled from column A, position 14-22
- Column 4 - Last Name, filled from
  column B, Truncated at 10, Left
  Justify & fill with blanks, position
  23-32
- Column 5 - First Name, filled from C,
  Truncate at 8, Left Justify & fill
  with blanks, position 33-40
- Column 6 - Total Gross Wages/Quarter,
  filled from D, strip all formatting,
  Right Justify Zero Fill, position
  41-49
- Column 7 - A Static Code, never
  changes, position 50-51
- Column 8 - BLANKS, Fill with blanks,
  position 52-80

I have, I assume, 3 options:

1. VBA
2. .NET
3. SQL

I had explored the .NET method first but I just couldn't find decent documentation to get me going.  I still like this one but I digress.

Next I have some VBA that will dump a Sheet to a fixed width Text.  I am currently pursuing this which leads, finally, to my actual question.

How do I transform a Range of text in Excel?  Do I need to coy it over to another sheet and then pass over that data with the neccesarry formatting functions the run my Dump to text routine?  I currently had planned to have a function for each column but I am having trouble figuring out how to take the next step.  I am fairly new at Office programming and developing in general so any insight will be greatly appreciated.

The SQL option would be my fall back as I have done similar exports from SQL in the past.  I just prefer the other two on the, *"I don't want to be responsible for running this,"* principle.

Thanks in advance for any time given.

Comment: Excellent question and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using VBA seems like the way to go to me. This lets you write a macro that takes care of all of the various formatting options and should, hopefully, be simple enough for your finance people to run themselves.

You said you need something that takes a sheet or range in Excel. The first column never changes so we can store that in the macro, columns 3-7 come from the spreadsheet and column 8 is just blank. That leaves column 2 (the quarter/year as QYY) as an issue. If the quarter/year is specified somewhere in the workbook (e.g. stored in a cell, as a worksheet name, as part of the workbook title) then we can just read it in. Otherwise you will need to find some method for specifying the quarter/year when the macro runs (e.g. pop up a dialog box and ask the user to input it)

Some simple code (we'll worry about how to call this later):

```
Sub ProduceStatePayrollReportFile(rngPayrollData As Range, strCompanyNo As String, _
    strQuarterYear As String, strRecordCode As String, strOutputFile As String)
```

The parameters are fairly obvious: the range that holds the data, the company number for column 1, the quarter/year for column 2, the fixed code for column 7 and the file we want to output the results to

```
' Store the file handle for the output file
Dim fnOutPayrollReport As Integer
' Store each line of the output file
Dim strPayrollReportLine As String
' Use to work through each row in the range
Dim indexRow As Integer
```

To output to a file in VBA we need to get a file handle so we need a variable to store that in. We'll build up each line of the report in the report line string and use the row index to work through the range

```
' Store the raw SSN, last name, first name and wages data
Dim strRawSSN As String
Dim strRawLastName As String
Dim strRawFirstName As String
Dim strRawWages As String
Dim currencyRawWages As Currency

' Store the corrected SSN, last name, first name and wages data
Dim strCleanSSN As String
Dim strCleanLastName As String
Dim strCleanFirstName As String
Dim strCleanWages As String
```

These sets of variables store the raw data from the worksheet and the cleaned data to be output to the file respectively. Naming them "raw" and "clean" makes it easier to spot errors where you accidentally output raw data instead of cleaned data. We will need to change the raw wages from a string value to a numeric value to help with the formatting

```
' Open up the output file
fnOutPayrollReport = FreeFile()
Open strOutputFile For Output As #fnOutPayrollReport
```

FreeFile() gets the next available file handle and we use that to link to the file

```
' Work through each row in the range
For indexRow = 1 To rngPayrollData.Rows.Count
    ' Reset the output report line to be empty
    strPayrollReportLine = ""
    ' Add the company number to the report line (assumption: already correctly formatted)
    strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strCompanyNo
    ' Add in the quarter/year (assumption: already correctly formatted)
    strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strQuarterYear
```

In our loop to work through each row, we start by clearing out the output string and then adding in the values for columns 1 and 2

```
' Get the raw SSN data, clean it and append to the report line
strRawSSN = rngPayrollData.Cells(indexRow, 1)
strCleanSSN = cleanFromRawSSN(strRawSSN)
strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strCleanSSN
```

The `.Cells(indexRow, 1)` part just means the left-most column of the range at the row specified by indexRow. If the ranges starts in column A (which does not have to be the case) then this just means A. We'll need to write the `cleanFromRawSSN` function ourselves later

```
' Get the raw last and first names, clean them and append them
strRawLastName = rngPayrollData.Cells(indexRow, 2)
strCleanLastName = Format(Left$(strRawLastName, 10), "!@@@@@@@@@@")
strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strCleanLastName

strRawFirstName = rngPayrollData.Cells(indexRow, 3)
strCleanFirstName = Format(Left$(strRawFirstName, 8), "!@@@@@@@@")
strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strCleanFirstName
```

`Left$(string, length)` truncates the string to the given length. The format picture `!@@@@@@@@@@` formats a string as exactly ten characters long, left justified (the ! signifies left justify) and padded with spaces

```
' Read in the wages data, convert to numeric data, lose the decimal, clean it and append it
strRawWages = rngPayrollData.Cells(indexRow, 4)
currencyRawWages = CCur(strRawWages)
currencyRawWages = currencyRawWages * 100
strCleanWages = Format(currencyRawWages, "000000000")
strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strCleanWages
```

We convert it to currency so that we can multiply by 100 to move the cents value to the left of the decimal point. This makes it much easier to use `Format` to generate the correct value. This will not produce correct output for wages >= $10 million but that's a limitation of the file format used for reporting. The `0` in the format picture pads with 0s surprisingly enough

```
' Append the fixed code for column 7 and the spaces for column 8
strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & strRecordCode
strPayrollReportLine = strPayrollReportLine & CStr(String(29, " "))

' Output the line to the file
Print #fnOutPayrollReport, strPayrollReportLine
```

The `String(number, char)` function produces a Variant with a sequence of `number` of the specified `char`. `CStr` turns the Variant into a string. The `Print #` statement outputs to the file without any additional formatting

```
Next indexRow

' Close the file
Close #fnOutPayrollReport

End Sub
```

Loop round to the next row in the range and repeat. When we have processed all of the rows, close the file and end the macro

We still need two things: a cleanFromRawSSN function and a way to call the macro with the relevant data.

```
Function cleanFromRawSSN(strRawSSN As String) As String

' Used to index the raw SSN so we can process it one character at a time
Dim indexRawChar As Integer

' Set the return string to be empty
cleanFromRawSSN = ""

' Loop through the raw data and extract the correct characters
For indexRawChar = 1 To Len(strRawSSN)
    ' Check for hyphen
    If (Mid$(strRawSSN, indexRawChar, 1) = "-") Then
        ' do nothing
    ' Check for space
    ElseIf (Mid$(strRawSSN, indexRawChar, 1) = " ") Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        ' Output character
        cleanFromRawSSN = cleanFromRawSSN & Mid$(strRawSSN, indexRawChar, 1)
    End If
Next indexRawChar

' Check for correct length and return empty string if incorrect
If (Len(cleanFromRawSSN) <> 9) Then
    cleanFromRawSSN = ""
End If

End Function
```

`Len` returns the length of a string and `Mid$(string, start, length)` returns `length` characters from `string` beginning at `start`. This function could be improved as it doesn't currently check for non-numeric data

To call the macro:

```
Sub CallPayrollReport()

ProduceStatePayrollReportFile Application.Selection, "1234560007", "109", "01", "C:\payroll109.txt"

End Sub
```

This is the simplest way to call it. The Range is whatever the user has selected on the active worksheet in the active workbook and the other values are hard-coded. The user should select the range they want to output to the file then go Tools > Macro > Run and choose `CallPayrollReport`. For this to work, the macro would either need to be part of the workbook containg the data or in a different workbook which had been loaded before the user calls the macro.

Someone would need to change the hard-coded value of the quarter/year before each quarter's report was generated. As stated earlier, if the quarter/year is already stored in the workbook somewhere then it's better to read that in rather than hard-coding it

Hope that makes sense and is of some use

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this strictly from the viewpoint of what's easiest for you, and if you are comfortable with SQL, in the context of Access, you could use Access to attach to the spreadsheet as an external datasource. It would look like a table in Access, and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!

I have to say, I am blown away.  You so far exceeded my expectations for an answer that I feel guilty that I can ONLY up vote you once and mark as excepted.  I had HOPED for so guidance towards which path was best and some formatting.  Well Happy Birthday to me!

The Format() and FreeFile() were especially new useful info.  Also, just to show that I was trying, my attempt is below.  I was quite close as I was just working out the formatting details but I believe I shall rework it with your input as it seems the more elegant approach.

As a final note.  I found this place thru Jeff Atwood's blog and I was truly excited by the idea.  As a new, inexperienced developer in a solo shop I had always wished there was someplace I could turn for mentorship.  Books and articles get you to a point but nothing equals the advice of someone who's done it or been there.  So far StackOverflow has delivered.

For reference, I posted this exact same question on another very popular Code Forum and have yet to receive a single response in any way.

Now for my attempt:

The Module Code

```
    Sub StateANSIIExport()
    Dim Sizes As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim aRow As Long, aCol As Long
    Dim rowLimit As Integer, colLimit As Integer
    Dim SpacesPerCell As Integer
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TheLine As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    rowLimit = UBound(arr, 1)
    'colLimit = UBound(arr, 2)
    colLimit = 8
    SpacesPerCell = 20      'Set export text "column" width here

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(GetDesktopPath() & "EXCELTEXT.txt", True)

    ' Loop thru the rows
    For aRow = 1 To rowLimit
        TheLine = Space(colLimit * SpacesPerCell)     ' your fixed-width output
        ' Loop thru the columns
        For aCol = 1 To colLimit
            Select Case aCol
                Case 1  ' Employer UI Account #
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = "6979430002"
                Case 2  ' Reporting Period (QYY)
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = "109"
                Case 3  ' SSN
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = Cells(aRow, "A")
                Case 4  ' Last Name
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = Cells(aRow, "B")
                Case 5  ' First Name
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = Cells(aRow, "C")
                Case 6  ' Employee Quartly Gross Wages
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = Cells(aRow, "D")
                Case 7   ' Record Code
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = "01"
                Case 8  ' BLANK
                    Mid(TheLine, aCol * SpacesPerCell - SpacesPerCell + 1, SpacesPerCell) = "                             "
            End Select
        Next aCol
        ' Write the line to the file
        ts.WriteLine TheLine
    Next aRow

    ts.Close

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

    Sub MacroToRunTwo()
    Dim S As String
    S = "Hello World From Two:" & vbCrLf & _
        "This Add-In File Name: " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
    MsgBox S
End Sub

Function GetDesktopPath() As String
'Return the current user's desktop path
GetDesktopPath = "C:\Users\patrick\Desktop\"
'GetDesktopPath = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Desktop\"
End Function
```

And The WorkBook Code:

```
    Private Const C_TAG = "Refracted Solutions" ' C_TAG should be a string unique to this add-in.
Private Const C_TOOLS_MENU_ID As Long = 30007&

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Workbook_Open
' Create a submenu on the Tools menu. The
' submenu has two controls on it.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim ToolsMenu As Office.CommandBarControl
Dim ToolsMenuItem As Office.CommandBarControl
Dim ToolsMenuControl As Office.CommandBarControl

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' First delete any of our controls that
' may not have been properly deleted previously.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
DeleteControls

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Get a reference to the Tools menu.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set ToolsMenu = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=C_TOOLS_MENU_ID)
If ToolsMenu Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to access Tools menu.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Create a item on the Tools menu.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set ToolsMenuItem = ToolsMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, temporary:=True)
If ToolsMenuItem Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to add item to the Tools menu.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With ToolsMenuItem
    .Caption = "&WWCares"
    .BeginGroup = True
    .Tag = C_TAG
End With

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Create the first control on the new item
' in the Tools menu.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set ToolsMenuControl = ToolsMenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
If ToolsMenuControl Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to add item to Tools menu item.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With ToolsMenuControl
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Set the display caption and the
    ' procedure to run when clicked.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    .Caption = "State ANSII E&xport"
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StateANSIIExport"
    .Tag = C_TAG
End With

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Create the second control on the new item
' in the Tools menu.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Set ToolsMenuControl = ToolsMenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
'If ToolsMenuControl Is Nothing Then
'    MsgBox "Unable to add item to Tools menu item.", vbOKOnly
'    Exit Sub
'End If

'With ToolsMenuControl
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Set the display caption and the
    ' procedure to run when clicked.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'    .Caption = "Click Me &Two"
'    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!MacroToRunTwo"
'    .Tag = C_TAG
'End With

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Workbook_BeforeClose
' Before closing the add-in, clean up our controls.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    DeleteControls
End Sub


Private Sub DeleteControls()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Delete controls whose Tag is
' equal to C_TAG.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim Ctrl As Office.CommandBarControl

On Error Resume Next
Set Ctrl = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:=C_TAG)

Do Until Ctrl Is Nothing
    Ctrl.Delete
    Set Ctrl = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:=C_TAG)
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the format of your document, I'd probably recommend exporting to .csv and working with that. If all you need is the numbers, this would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I believe I am confused though.  What document are you referring to the "format" of?  I tried to outline that in my post.  Second, what do I gain by changing my xls into a csv?

Thanks Again!